# How to use toMatchSnapshot with enzyme so the result is similar to container.firstChil with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a simple application with enzyme and I just want to render the html nodes and not the component:

```js
const container = mount(<Hello />);

expect(toJson(container)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

current result:

```html
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`Hello should render 1`] = `
 <Hello>
   <a />
 </Hello>
`
```

expected result:

```html
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`Hello should render 1`] = `
 <a />
`
```

with react-testing-library would be just to get the container.firstChild but I'm not sure how to accomplish the same with enzyme

Answer (score 0):

Usually Enzyme in not supposed to be used for snapshot testing (based on my experience), you should consider to use `react-test-renderer` just to check  the snapshot and use enzyme to other kind of tests like, for example, find an instance of component or to test a method of your class based component. If you really want to use Enzyme to do snapshot testing you may use this: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/html.html#examples